# Can not add content to nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, blazor-component

I created a blazor component library; when the project was created, it included scaffolded.cs and.js files with the names exampleJsInterop.

I also made a blazor app to test the component library by referencing it.

I created a nuget package of the component library today in order to install it in my blazor app. and I have immediately noticed that the exampleJsInterop is not working.

**exampleJsInterop Implementation**

```
public class exampleJsInterop : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    public exampleJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new (() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import", "./_content/MyComponentProject/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
    }
 
}
```

**Part of .Nuspec**

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\net7.0\MyComponentProject.dll" target="lib\net7.0" />
    <file src="wwwroot\exampleJsInterop.js" target="wwwroot/MyComponentProject" />
    <file src="wwwroot\exampleJsInterop.js"  target="_content/MyComponentProject/exampleJsInterop.js"/>
</files>
```

Expectation: After implementing the above lines into the nuspec file I would expected to see the exampleJsInterop.js file under the wwwroot or _content but I do not.

and I get the following error messages when I try to invoke js methods from exampleJsInterop.js

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
- Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:13373/_content/MyComponentProject/exampleJsInterop.js

is there anything I'm doing wrong or missing with the nuspec file? any help with more experience is much appreciated.